# R knitr: force linebreak in headline

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, knitr, bookdown

I would like to force a linebreak in a long headline in an R markdown file knitted with knitr to both PDF and HTML output. At best, referencing of the headline should still work.
The following solutions proposed for related issues did not solve the issue: `\\`, `\n`, `<br>`, `<br>` (the latter two work for HTML only).

```
  ---
  title: "TEST"
  author: "Tester"
  output:
    pdf_document: default
    html_document:
      df_print: paged
  ---

  # Fancy long headline in R Markdown

  \newpage

  # Not working:

  ## Fancy long headline in \\ R Markdown

  # Work in HTML only:

  ## Fancy long headline in <br> R Markdown

  ## Fancy long headline in <br /> R Markdown

  <!-- ## Fancy long headline in   \n R Markdown -->
  <!-- => `  \n` throws error in LaTex -->

  \newpage

  # Reference the headline

  Reference the [fancy long headline in r markdown] 
  or similarly in bookdown [fancy-long-headline-in-r-markdown] 
  or via [myref](fancy-long-headline-in-r-markdown).
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may consider using a Pandoc Lua filter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52193443/559676

Comment: Truly seems to be an option, though the recent answers by user2554330 and @Taufi appear quicker to use in simple Rmds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you were almost there. You need to put the Latex Code in `$...$`. Using this code

```
---
title: "TEST"
author: "Tester"
output:
  pdf_document: default
html_document:
  df_print: paged
---

  # Fancy long headline in R Markdown

  \newpage

# Working!

## Fancy long headline in $\\$ <br> R Markdown
```

gives

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and elegant response @Taufi! Adding `$\\$ <br>` well takes care of both use cases. Surprisingly `[fancy long headline in $\\$ <br> r markdown] ` works to reference the headline, however, it includes a linebreak itself. Would you have any advice on improved referencing, at best without adding a label?

Comment: When using `# Fancy long headline in $\\$ <br> R Markdown` in `bookdown`/`thesisdown` unfortunately I run into the following error: "/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end."

Comment: You're welcome! Unfortunately I do not know enough about bookdown/thesisdown to help you out here, sorry :(

Comment: This seems to work with @Taufi's solution:  `Reference the [Fancy long headline in R Markdown](#fancy-long-headline-in-r-markdown)` in both PDF and HTML.  You should accept their answer!

Comment: @user2554330: Taufi's solution works well for a simple markdown file, true.

Comment: For all those seeking for a solution for `bookdown`/`thesisdown`: use @user2554330 approach and create chapter/section headings with "\chapter[headline without linebreak for TOC]{headline with `r Linebreak()` linebreak\label{my-label}}". Then referencing this headline with `\@ref(my-label)` works well, but unfortunately not with `[headline](#my-label)`. Note also that user2554330 approach does not work well with HTML output

Answer (score 2):

If you want something that will work in PDF but don't care about HTML, define a new LaTeX command and use that.  For example,

```
\newcommand{\Linebreak}{\\}

## Fancy long headline in \Linebreak R Markdown
```

If you want it to work in both, this should do it:

````
\newcommand{\Linebreak}{\\}
```{r include = FALSE}
Linebreak <- function()
  if (knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to") == "html")
    " <BR> " else " \\Linebreak "
```

## Fancy long headline in `r Linebreak()` R Markdown
````

It's not too hard to get the reference to work in PDF, but appears to be tricky in HTML; I'll leave that to you or someone else to work out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input, @user2554330! Output and, at best, also referencing is needed for both PDF and HTML.

Comment: If using `# Fancy long headline in `r Linebreak()` R Markdown` in `bookdown`/`thesisdown`, the headline title in the TOC will obviously contain a linebreak as-well. The workaround "\chapter[Fancy long headline in R Markdown]{Fancy long headline in `r Linebreak()` R Markdown\label{mylabel}}" works well for me in PDF, but not at all in HTML. Would you have any advice?